# Casting objects in JRuby

Tags: java, jruby

I still don't feel like this is adequately answered. how does one do this in jruby:

```
MyClass myobj = new MyClass;
InheritsFromMyClass changedobj = (InheritsFromMyClass)myobj;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ruby is a dynamically typed language you do not need to cast the type:

```
myobj = MyClass.new
changedobj = myobj
```

Comment: what happens when `changedobj.method_that_is_only_on_inherits_from_my_class`

Comment: i think this question is stemming from my complete lack of java knowledge. It works, thank you